How to get a list of rules associated with a dataplex scan
I have created a data quality scan with few DQ rules using the dataplex UI and I am trying to use the python sdk to retrive the scan details and the rules associated with it. All I am getting in the response are the basic details (below) about the scan but not the rules attached to it.
Request
dplex_client = dataplex_v1.DataScanServiceClient()
dplex_scan = dplex_client.get_data_scan(name=scan_name)
print(dplex_scan)

Response
name: "projects/dataplexlabs/locations/us-central1/dataScans/customer-master-dq-scan---validity"
uid: "d95fc1c7-c753-4c8c-b54b-cef86"
display_name: "Customer Master DQ Scan - VALIDITY"
state: ACTIVE
create_time {
  seconds: 1733145723
  nanos: 464115546
}
update_time {
  seconds: 1733205910
  nanos: 619511184
}
data {
  resource: "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/dataplexlabs/datasets/oda_dq_scratch_ds/tables/customer_master"
}
execution_spec {
  trigger {
    on_demand {
    }
  }
}
execution_status {
  latest_job_start_time {
    seconds: 1733195907
    nanos: 520000000
  }
  latest_job_end_time {
    seconds: 1733195934
    nanos: 700244331
  }
  latest_job_create_time {
    seconds: 1733195907
    nanos: 79438962
  }
}
type_: DATA_QUALITY

What's the correct way to get these all the details of a scan please?
